# Unable to resolve Type error using Tokenizer.tokenize from NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, tokenization

I want to tokenize text data and am unable to proceed due to a type error, am unable to know how to proceed to rectify the error, To give some context - all the columns - Resolution code','Resolution Note','Description','Shortdescription' are text data in English- here is the code that I have written :

#Removal of Stop words:

```
    from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
    from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')        
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+') 
    dfclean_imp_netc=pd.DataFrame() 
    for column in ['Resolution code','Resolution Note','Description','Shortdescription']:
        dfimpnetc[column] = dfimpnetc[column].apply(tokenizer.tokenize)        
    for column in ['Resolution code','Resolution Note','Description','Short description']:
        dfclean_imp_netc[column] = dfimpnetc[column].apply(lambda vec: [word for word in vec if word not in stop_words]) 
    dfimpnetc['Resolution Note'] = dfclean_imp_netc['Resolution Note'] 
    dfimpnetc['Description'] = dfclean_imp_netc['Description'] 
    dfimpnetc['Short description'] = dfclean_imp_netc['Short description'] 
    dfimpnetc['Resolution code'] = dfclean_imp_netc['Resolution code']
```

My error output is attached below:
[image]

Comment: Where do you expect that the data would come from? You initialize a dataframe, but I fail to spot where you load in data.

Comment: I have loaded the data at line 15, the dataframe dfimpnetc has already been loaded with data from a csv file earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
w_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()

dfimpnetc[column] = dfimpnetc[column].apply(lambda x: [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in w_tokenizer.tokenize(x)])
```

Try the above code.

Mark as correct if this helps ;)

Comment: Am thankful for the suggestion @William Scott however am still getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `S van Balen` in that it's not clear where and whether you actually load the data. Even if you loaded it earlier, initializing a new `DataFrame` object might erase it from memory if you're using the same variable name to store it.

Anyway, assuming the `DataFrame 'dfclean_imp_netc'`'s rows and columns have indeed been filled with values, then I think the issue is that you initialize the frame as `dfclean_imp_netc` but then you apply the tokenizer on a different variable, `dfimpnetc`. I think you need to move the assignment of values to `dfimpnetc` before the `for` loops, as shown in the code snippet below.

Please note also that the two `for` loops are not assigning values to the same variable: the first `loop` updates `dfimpnetc` but the second loop updates `dfclean_imp_netc`. I get the sense you may want to be updating the same variable in both cases.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')        
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+') 
dfclean_imp_netc=pd.DataFrame() 
dfimpnetc['Resolution Note'] = dfclean_imp_netc['Resolution Note'] 
dfimpnetc['Description'] = dfclean_imp_netc['Description'] 
dfimpnetc['Short description'] = dfclean_imp_netc['Short description'] 
dfimpnetc['Resolution code'] = dfclean_imp_netc['Resolution code']

for column in ['Resolution code','Resolution Note','Description','Shortdescription']:
    dfimpnetc[column] = dfimpnetc[column].apply(tokenizer.tokenize)        
for column in ['Resolution code','Resolution Note','Description','Short description']:
    dfclean_imp_netc[column] = dfimpnetc[column].apply(lambda vec: [word for word in vec if word not in stop_words])
```